# Convert hash-like String to Hash & security risks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using JavaScript to turn user input into a String that looks like an array of hashes and pass it to a hidden field in a Rails form. I.e. something like this gets passed to my controller:

```html
<input id="UserHash" name="UserHash" type="hidden" value="[{ :payer_id => 1, :amt => 90.00}, { :payer_id => 2, :amt => 80.00}, { :payer_id => 4, :amt => 20.00}]">
```

and I'm using `eval(params[:UserHash])` to turn it into a Hash I can work with. Am I completely compromising security by using `eval()`, and if so, is there a way I can check that the string passed is an array of hashes? Any input on what I'm doing would be appreciated. The reason I'm using JS to pass an array of hashes is because my form collects data about a variable-length collection (a variable set of Payers).

Comment: Yes, you are completely compromising security by using `eval`. Why not just use JSON to store and retrieve the hash? Decoding that is perfectly safe, and it offers more or less (well, more) the same conciseness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use JSON instead.

This is exactly the scenario JSON has been designed for. Create a JSON string in Javascript and the parse it in Ruby with

```
require 'json'

string = '[{"payer_id":1,"amt":90.0},{"payer_id":2,"amt":80.0},{"payer_id":4,"amt":20.0}]'
data = JSON.parse(string)
```

it will turn your string into an array of hashes.

**Note,** if you want the keys to be symbols, use

```
data = JSON.parse(string,:symbolize_names=>true)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, now I'm getting a nil object error ("You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!") on the line when I call: data.detect { |payer| payer[:payer_id] == var }[:amt], immediately afterwards. Even when I just hardcode the string you gave me and use that instead, and hardcode var to one of the payer_ids, I get the same error.

Comment: When I output JSON.parse(string) in the console (during debugging) I get:{"payer_id"=>1, "amt"=>25.0}
{"payer_id"=>2, "amt"=>25.0}
{"payer_id"=>4, "amt"=>25.0}
{"payer_id"=>5, "amt"=>25.0}  ... There are no braces around this value, could that be the issue?

Comment: You are trying to access with symbols, but the keys are strings. You have to do it like this `data.detect { |payer| payer['payer_id'] == var }['amt']`

Comment: Added a note on how to get symbolized names.